# how can i unset a global variable in function

Tags: php

I try the code bellow

```
function unsetvalue()
{
  global $name;
  unset($name);
}  

$name = "john";
unsetvalue();
echo $name;
```

The output of this code is "john"

but if we try unset out of the function like bellow

```
$name = "john";
unset($name);
echo $name;
```

the output will be undefined variable error

my question is why my unsetvalue function not work ?

Comment: Use `unset($GLOBALS['name']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unset the variable directly in the array `$GLOBALS` :

```
function unsetvalue()
{
  unset($GLOBALS['name']);
}  

$name = "john";
unsetvalue();
echo $name; // Output : Undefined variable: name in  ...
```